# How do you change fill color for different calls of geom_sf?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I'm working on plotting sf objects in ggplot2. I have a set of polygons `buffered` that have a density value for each polygon `density`. I want to plot this along with a single sf point `GPS_point` as a reference point. The problem I am running into is that I cannot set the `fill` color separately for each object.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = buffered, aes(fill = density),lwd = 0) + #polygons filled based on the density value
  geom_sf(data = GPS_point, aes(fill = "red"), size = 5) + #reference point that I want to make red
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "magma",begin = 0.1)
```

I am trying to set the reference point fill color to red. The current code sets the fill for both objects as `magma`. The problem is that this makes the reference point indistinguishable from the background because they end up as the same color. Is there any way to manipulate the fill color separately for these two `geom_sf` calls?

Comment: when you put the fill inside of `aes()` it will treat it as a variable and use your color palette. To get your desired outcome, remove simply put `fill = 'red'` outside of the aesthetic.

Comment: I gave that a go, but it is still displaying the color as black (which is the 0 value for the `magma` color palette)

Comment: ah, I overlooked the fact that the correct parameter for point data is `col` or `colour` and not `fill` !

Comment: That worked. Thanks!

Comment: @zx8754 have done now, thanks

Comment: @Chris with 18K views in 4 years, you missed out on many upvotes :)

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax for passing a hardcoded colour to a geom is to put it outside of the `aes`:

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = buffered, aes(fill = density),lwd = 0) + #polygons filled based on the density value
  geom_sf(data = GPS_point, fill = "red", size = 5) + #reference point that I want to make red
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "magma",begin = 0.1)
```

The difference is that `aes` expects a variable (as you pass 'density' in the first `geom_sf` call), which it will use to graduate the fill depending on the value that variable takes. Hardcoded colours eg 'red' should be passed without an `aes`